# tweak the jquery below so that the page down scrolls 1"

Tags: jquery, css

http://communitychessclub.com/index.php is a long web page that uses a permanent position:fixed menu based on code from http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html

But the menu contains links to ID's in the same page, and when clicked, the fixed scrolling menu obstructs part of the . For example: http://communitychessclub.com/#official and you see the menu blocking the target article text. Note that I have  and that's the logical syntax and location I want.

Is there a way to modify the jquery below so that the page down scrolls 1" to make the menu appear off the target article? I don't care if the menu is covering the article above the target ID article.

```
CSS:
#sticky {margin:0 auto; display:table}
#sticky.stick {position: fixed;  top: 0; margin-left:48px; z-index: 10000; }

JS:

<script>
function sticky_relocate() {
var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
if (window_top > div_top)
$('#sticky').addClass('stick')
else
$('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
}

$(function() {
$(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
sticky_relocate();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of JavaScript will work.

```
$(window).scroll((function() {
var a='',  // a buffer to the hash
w = $(window);
return function() {
    var h = location.hash;
    if (h != a) {   // if hash is different from the previous one, which indicates
                        // the hash changed by user, then scroll the window down
    a = h;           // update the buffer
    w.scrollTop(w.scrollTop()-100)
    }
};
})());
```

Comment: Good work! But see: http://communitychessclub.com/mparry.php (an external file) and click on the menu faq --> "why did you start this website?" and you will see that the original problem remains.

Comment: I think you can change `var a=location.hash` to `var a=''` (I've edited in the answer)

Comment: That is an improvement. However when the target ID is accessed the top of the web page, the results are different than when the target id is accessed from the menu from the middle body of the web page. IDK if this can be fixed.

Comment: When user refreshes page (F5) from http://communitychessclub.com/#official, the page has dropped 150px. Can this be fixed?

Comment: I didn't repro the refresh bug in Chrome. For the ids in the top, you could add a condition `window.scrollTop() === 0` to judge whether it should be scroll down 150px.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not provided in that code.

Basically, the idea is to capture the click event, get the id of the article you want to move to, find the position().top of that element, and then move the window to that location - some distance.

```
$('.js-css-menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).scrollTop($('#' + $(this).prop('href').split('#')[1]).offset().top - 50);
});​
```

This looks good in the console.

Comment: Thank you, but this code seems sub-optimal in that it dw. Sorry!

Comment: I think I need instructions how to integrate into the existing code. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know where to put your code. Your code looks excellent. Lucid and correct. Can you show me where I can replace the old code with your code? I would really like to try it!